# android find and remove duplicates in array string

Tags: android, arrays

in my android app, i get data of my mysql database and put this into a string array. now i would like to check if there duplicates in the array and remove them, but i don't know how.

Comment: Maybe think of a logic and write some code?

Comment: i only would to know if there is a function for this or if i have to check it with a simple if else function